# Unexpected windows batch behaviour - Variable reset after assignment - Getting file date using FOR %f in FILE and SET

Tags: windows, date, variables, batch-file, reset

I am trying to compare the creation date of a file to today's date, and have a working solution:

```
FOR %%f IN (%ARCHIVE_FILE%) DO SET FileDate=%%~tf
IF [%FileDate:~0,-6%] == [%CURRENT_DATE%] goto finish
```

For some reason, when deploying this batch script on a Windows machine other than the ones I've tested on (two different Windows machines), the FileDate variable is set to the expected result, e.g. "dd/mm/yy mm:ss", and then reset to nothing.

Putting:

```
echo %FileDate%
pause
```

Between the two lines shows the FileDate being assigned correctly and then being assigned to "" straight after.
I cannot find an answer on this, and wondered if there are any rare .batch masters who might have some idea of what's going on :/.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

Moved to a forfiles solution, which I will add for anyone looking for an alternative:

```
forfiles /p %ARCHIVE_DIR% /m %FILE_NAME% /d 0 && (
  goto finish
) || (
  goto start
)
```

This should suffice, I have yet to check it on the machine I need it for.

It would still be nice to find out why the above initial solution failed horribly, haha.

Comment: Are the two lines surrounded by another loop or something else?

Comment: This is just a section of the overall batch file, just some file transfers done after, no surrounding parentheses. Works on all of my machines, it must be some sort of odd windows setup?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that your code is different from that part you posted.

These types of problems normally occours in command blocks surrounded by parenthesis.
It's a problem of the expansion phases of the batch parser, as percent expansion occours before a block is executed.
So you should switch to delayed expansion

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%f IN (%ARCHIVE_FILE%) DO (
  SET "FileDate=%%~tf"
  echo Doesn't work %FileDate%
  echo But this works !FileDate!
  IF "!FileDate:~0,-6!" == "%CURRENT_DATE%" goto finish
)
:finish
```

Comment: I use the two lines that I originally posted, in that format. It's odd that it works on one machine and not on another..
This is useful to know however.

Comment: Would you advise using this over the forfiles alternative?

Comment: @user3906990 No, I would use the `forfiles` solution

Comment: Okay, thanks. Do you think that the forfiles solution is pretty safe?

Comment: @permafrost Looks very safe, but you could enclose `%ARCHIVE_DIR%` and `%FILE_NAME%` with quotes to avoid problems with spaces and other nasty characters